# Having issues with blob

Tags: google-chrome, blob

I am getting following errors all the time but can not figure out where they are coming from.

`GET blob:http://localhost:3000/654e7fc8-56e3-40f7-b632-6ef64c9b2a15 0 ()
GET blob:http://widget.cloudinary.com/8009b7ef-fd0a-40ca-8d1f-ab5ae6ded8ea`

Like this is connected to every "blob".

I am using Chrome. How can I debug this?
If you need more data, please let me know.

Comment: IIRC, this is an adblocker extension.

Comment: I tried to disable Adblock, still getting `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND blob:http://localhost:3000/d3f53612-9a1a-4237-9a58-fdbcdb06d94d:1`

Comment: Try turning off all extensions, then enabling one at a time.

Comment: turning of adblock worked for me